# Map 2 arrays to list of objects with each array as a property

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

In kentico categories for pages are held in an object called `IInfoObjectCollection`.  Weirdly, it holds the category details in separate arrays so the category ids are held in an array of Guids and then the category names are held in an array of strings in this object collection

Example of the type of class I have in the kentico treenode:

```
public class InfoObjectCollection 
{
   public Guid[] CategoryIDs { get; set; }
   public string[] Names { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a category class:

```
public class Category
{
   public Guid CategoryID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to use automapper and linq (or not) to map the InfoObject into a collection of  categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AM seems overkill

```
source.CategoryIDs.Zip(source.Names, (id, name)=>new Category { CategoryID = id, Name = name});
```

Comment: Nice zip is what I was after - is there a version of this that would allow for more than 2 (incase I need extra properties in future)

Comment: You zip two collections, so you would need to group them or smth.